# Fetch data for non table entity in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have user table with column id, mname, firstname, lastname, age (5 column)
using spring data jpa I need to get only id, firstname, age (only 3 column)

userentity is below user.java

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
   public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "mname")
    private String mName;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="age")
    private int age;

    //constructor with fileds


user2.java contains the fileds

private Long id;
private String firstname;
private int age;

//getter and setter
```

UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
@Query(value="SELECT usr.id as id,usr.firstname as firstName, usr.age as age FROM user usr WHERE usr.id=?1", nativeQuery=true)
List<User2> getUserDetailsByUserId(Long id);
}
```

getting the below error in colsole:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type [java.math.BigInteger]
>   to type [com.user.entity.User2]

while inspect the code get the error:

> Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type
>   [com.user.entity.User2] for value '{403, firstnnnnnnn, 26}';

Is there any way to map the values to user2 (non-table entity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections):

[Interface based](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces):

```
public interface UserProjection {
    Long getId();
    String getFirstname();
    Integer getAge();
}

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    List<UserProjection> findById(Long id);
}
```

[Class based (DTO)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos):

```
@Value // It's Lombok annotation
public class UserDto {
    Long id;
    String firstname;
    Integer age;
}

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    List<UserProjection> findById(Long id);
    List<UserDto> getById(Long id);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cepr0, The Solution which you provided using projection is perfectly match with my requirement. Thanks for your solution.